# Inserting data into a child table based on master table primary key values

Tags: mysql, transactions

I'm currently working with an e-commerce shopping site. It's quite unnecessary to describe that users can submit their orders from anywhere at any time.

I have two tables in MySql database `order` and `order_details` (and there are others too) to maintain the order details that we can easily imagine therefore I think, I need not describe the whole structure of both of the tables.

The `order` table basically contains the fields like `order_id` which an auto-incremented primary key, `order_date`, `order_status` and some others that we don't need in this context.

The `order_details` table basically contains the fields like `order_id` which a *foreign key* of the `order` table, `product_name`, `product_price` etc.

When a customer submits an order, the first entry which is to be made is in the `order` table and based on the `order_id` in this table, the details of this order is inserted into the `order_details` table.

Inserting into the `order_details` table requires an appropriate `order_id` to be fetched from the **order** table (which is auto-incremented and therefore, we can not have it in advance). I'm currently fetching this `order_id` from the `order` table something like this.

```
select max(order_id) from order;
```

This SQL statement gives me the latest `order_id` from the `order` table and using this value, I can insert the details of the particular order into the `order_details` table.

Now, let's assume that I'm currently submitting an order containing some products in the shopping cart. My order is inserted into the `order` table successfully but before inserting into the `order_details` (and before retrieving the **max** `order_id` from the `order` table), this process is switched away by the operating system scheduler on the server for some reasons to execute another customer's order and the processing of that another customer's order is fully completed (inserted into both of the tables, the `order` and the `order_details`).

After completing this order processing (that another customer's order), my order which is still pending starts executing which was switched away before retrieving the **max** `order_id` from the `order` table. When the above SQL statement is executed, it will fetch the `max` `order_id` from the `order` table which is relevant to that another customer's order and **not** relevant to mine resulting the transaction in an **inconsistent** state!

What I want to ask is that how to correctly fetch an appropriate `order_id` from the `order` table which is always relevant to a particular order and that guarantees that ***no transaction ends with an inconsistent*** state at any time. What's the correct way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function will return the auto-incremented value from the first successful insert of the last `INSERT` operation on the current connection.

Your MySQL API will usually provide some wrapper around this function call, e.g. [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) in PHP.

Comment: Suppose, my order is in the pending state (after inserting into the `order` table only). Later, my order starts processing after completing let's say 10 orders, would `LAST_INSERT_ID()` guarantee that the `order_id` being retrieved from the `order` table is always associated with **my** order?

Comment: @Bhavesh: Provided that the other orders were inserted over different connections to the MySQL database, yes.

Comment: `last_insert_id(order_id)` is retrieving all the `order_id`s unique to a particular connection. I however, want only the latest from among them.

Comment: @Bhavesh: You call it without any argument.

Comment: `last_insert_id()` retrieves all `0`s.

Comment: May I use something like this `max(last_insert_id(order_id))`. It retrieves only the latest value.

Comment: @Bhavesh: I think you should post the code that you are using.  It sounds like you're calling `LAST_INSERT_ID()` incorrectly.

Comment: I'm just trying this SQL statement in MySql `select last_insert_id(order_id) from order_table`. The `order` table right now contains only 8 rows (which are unique only to my connection) with the `order_id` `2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9`.  The function `last_insert_id(order_id)` is giving me all the rows `2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9` and  `last_insert_id()` is giving me all the zeros 8 times. The code on the server side script PHP, Java is completely irrelevant. It's relevant only to a specific SQL statement with a specific function, I think.

Comment: I meant, post it (as an edit to your question) as used in your application in the context of your `INSERT` statement.  And you don't call `FROM ...`: just `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`.

Comment: The `INSERT` statement is vary long that I think no one is interested in.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11062/discussion-between-eggyal-and-bhavesh)