# LAST_INSERT_ID( ) returning multiple rows of 0?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, debugging

Working in phpMyAdmin for now:

`order` table strucure:

```
OrderID     int(11)  auto_increment
CustomerID  varchar(50)
BillAddr    varchar(200)
ShipAddr    varchar(200)
Date            date
Total           double
```

The table currently has 4 rows of data, with different OrderIDs.

SQL:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM `order`
```

Result:

```
LAST_INSERT_ID()
0
0
0
0
```

I was expecting the fourth rows `OrderID` - just one number but got a 0 for each row in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: No you can't use this function in this way.

Comment: The MySql `LSAT_INSERT_ID()` function is analogous to the PHP `mysql_insert_id( )` function. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644468/retrieving-the-last-insert-id-from-mysql-using-php)  and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518831/inserting-data-into-a-child-table-based-on-master-table-primary-key-values) questions for more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the id of the last inserted row and is not bound to any table. So if you create a new row:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES('a', 'b', 'c');
```

It will return the last id (whatever value the new primary key has).

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
=> 123
```

For details, please take a look at [**the manual**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

> LAST_INSERT_ID() (with no argument) returns a BIGINT (64-bit) value representing the first automatically generated value that was set for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the most recently executed INSERT statement to affect such a column. For example, after inserting a row that generates an AUTO_INCREMENT value, you can get the value like this:

If you just want to get last ID in a table, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: The last query returns the largest insert id - not the the most recent. And it's not bound to the session. There are very important semantic differences between the 2 methods. (I'm not saying iblue's code is wrong - just that it's very dangerous to assume that it's the same as last_insert_id())

Comment: @symcbean if your Id column is autoincrement, then the largest id will suffice. The downside is that if the largest Id row was deleted, then the previous one is returned, which may break some business functions

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

> [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) (with no argument) returns a [`BIGINT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/integer-types.html) (64-bit) value representing the *first* automatically generated value that was set for an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column by the *most recently executed* [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html) statement to affect such a column. For example, after inserting a row that generates an `AUTO_INCREMENT` value, you can get the value like this:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
>         -> 195
> ```

Comment: I am interpreting this statement as it should return the last auto_increment value from the last insert, however, I added the 'order' since I have multiple tables...looks like the most recently executed INSERT covers that

Comment: @GregMcNulty: You should remove `... FROM order` (as it only causes the same result of evaluating `LAST_INSERT_ID()` once to be returned for each record in the `order` table, which is not what you want).  And you should run the resulting `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` query (as shown in the quote above) immediately after executing an `INSERT` statement.  If that's not what you're after, please provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO `one`(`id`, `name`) VALUES (NULL,'shivam');
select last_insert_id();
```

Perform no other query after insert and they both should execute together

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, solution was do the the query at the same time. In other words first query and the second(last_insert_id) query should be executed at the same time. Not as two different execution.

Answer (score 0):

by indicating a table, you repeat the select statement for EVERY row in said table.

it does not affect the result of your query, other than to repeat the same value.

if running in phpmyadmin, you might want to check that Persistent Connections is set to TRUE, otherwise you will ALWAYS receive 0 as a result of LAST_INSERT_ID().