# Inserting row in mysql db with with insert_last_insert_ID

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm making a website where users should be able to input data by forms.
Because of this I need to input a row into the first table, and after insert a row in the second table, using the vo2testID from the first table which is a auto incremented foreign key.

[image: table 2]
[image: table 1]

My problem is when I try to insert something into the second table using this query:

```
INSERT INTO vo2phases_tb (VO2_TestID, Phase, Time, Intensity, RER, Borgscale, Pulse) 
VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'1', '12:00:00', '10', '23.5', '5', '110');
```

I get this error:

[image]

I have looked around for a solution but the only one i found was to disable the foreign key check, and I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

See documentation from [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

> With no argument, LAST_INSERT_ID() returns a BIGINT UNSIGNED (64-bit) value representing the first automatically generated value successfully inserted for an AUTO_INCREMENT column as a result of the most recently executed INSERT statement.

`LAST_INSERT_ID` works globally. Given the naming I suppose inserts are made into `vo2phases_tb` multiple times for each `VO2_TestID`. Thus, the insert query will fail on the second insert since the most recently inserted it is not a valid foreign key.

Solution would be to extract the `VO2_TestID` right after inserting and hand it down ownwards. This is also useful if multiple tests are executed at the same time and eliminates concurrency issues.

Comment: I didn't think about that thank you, I will store in a variable for later use. I still have the problem though that 'LAST_INSERT_ID()' doesnt get last inserted id. i tried makng a simpel 'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()' and it returns a zero.

Comment: Maybe that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302377/last-insert-id-returning-multiple-rows-of-0

Answer (score 0):

You should try stashing the value of LAST_INSERT_ID() in a user-defined variable. For example.

```
 INSERT INTO vo2test_tb (blah blah blah) VALUES (blah blah blah);
 SET @testId := LAST_INSERT_ID();
 INSERT INTO vo2phases_tb 
             (VO2_TestID, Phase, Time, Intensity, RER, Borgscale, Pulse)
      VALUES (@testId, blah blah blah);

 INSERT INTO vo2phases_tb 
             (VO2_TestID, Phase, Time, Intensity, RER, Borgscale, Pulse) 
      VALUES (@testId, blah blah blah);

 INSERT INTO vo2phases_tb 
             (VO2_TestID, Phase, Time, Intensity, RER, Borgscale, Pulse) 
      VALUES (@testId, blah blah blah);
```

That way each child row can get the correct parent-row id.