# Possible to insert into two tables where one of the table is shortage of auto_increment_ID?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
Table Product
pid  product_name

Table Category 
cid category_name

Table Product_category
cid pid
```

For table Product and Category, their primary keys are "pid and cid" with auto_increment

For product_category table, its used to store the data where 1 product is assigned to multiple categories and thats why the table columns are "cid and pid"

**I am using php+mysql to write some functions like creating new product, category and then assign product to one or multiple categories.**

Assume that we have created a 2 categories with cid-> 1,2

3 steps to assign product to category

1. add new product so that we have pid->123
2. then assign this product into category cid->1
3. insert into database table Product_category with pid->123 and cid->1

I want to do something simple like this instead
1. add new product and assign this product to category at the same time

**However, for Table Product_category, it needs 2 value which are pid and cid , so that means we only know this pid after creating new product as its auto_increment. So my question is how to know this pid when adding new product? OR its impossible to do it this way?**

```
public function conn(){

    $this->db_host="localhost";
    $this->db_name="bs";
    $this->db_user_name="root";
    $this->db_pass="";

    return mysqli_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user_name, $this->db_pass, $this->db_name);
}

$query = "INSERT item(uid,item_id,item_name,item_price,item_quantity) 
                    VALUES('$this->user_uid','$this->item_id','$this->item_name','$this->item_price','$this->item_quantity')";

    if (!mysqli_query($this->conn(), $query)) {
        echo "Failed to Add item!" . mysqli_error($query);
        return false;
    }else{
        printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysqli_insert_id($this->conn()));
        return true;
    }
```

[image]

I try to test by adding new records, but it always get this

"Last inserted record has id 0"

Comment: Look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: @AndrejLudinovskov i always get the result  -> 0 by using mysqli_insert_id

Comment: Post db schema here.

Comment: @AndrejLudinovskov plz check again

Comment: Show the code for method $this->conn().

Comment: just posted. plz check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your mistake is the method conn. Because you create a new connection for every call $this->conn(). A new connection doesn't know anything about INSERT statement that was performed in previous connection that is why `mysqli_insert_id` returns 0. A quick solution is to define a new var `$conn = $this->conn();` and use this one in all queries.

Comment: hmm, if thats the case, that means i didn't use the correct approach of connecting to database? My understanding is that for every select,insert of delete being done, i will close the connection - mysqli_close($this->conn()); . So what you are saying is that we shouldn't close the connection after the query? plz advice, thx

Comment: No, you shouldn't. Keep it open during the whole php-process.

Comment: so you mean if i want to use mysqli_insert_id , i cant use  conn() method ? that I have to duplicate the connection coding and specially use it for mysqli_insert_id ?. hmm?

Answer (score 1):

I think your SQL required `mysql_last_id` so it should be like this

```
INSERT INTO Product VALUES(null, product_name);
$product_last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO Category VALUES($product_last_id, category_name);
$category_last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO Product_category VALUES($product_last_id, $category_last_id);
```

Have a look at [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html).

Comment: i always get 0 for  LAST_INSERT_ID(); . and for your coding, can you edit it properly so that i can test directly on mysql? ignore the php coding.  thx

Comment: @gosulove i don't have your column. First, you try first query and check last_insert_id.

Comment: by right, this function will return the ID (auto-increment) of the last row right? so if i type this "select LAST_INSERT_ID()" into sql, it should return the value of that ID but it always get 0 no matter which table i try.

Comment: Kindly check this answer for returning value 0 http://stackoverflow.com/a/11302401/3081659

Comment: i posted more details, have a look

Comment: Why you select last_insert_id ? I think you should have to insert into the second query directly. In this case both query run at same time and insert the last id to the second query. product last_insert_id insert into the category.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set 2 database call first is product table. Insert a product. Then you will get the return value as `pid`, and I think you will get the `cid` from the page itself. You will select the option the new products belongs to which category then you can pass the `cid`. Then you can set the second database call `insertProduct_categoryTable(cid,pid)`.

Comment: I did mention in the question that this way of doing is troublesome and thats why i want to use something easier